# In What Order Should I Send My Vertices To OpenGL for Culling

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl

I'm learning a spot of 3d opengl, and it's going rather well, I've got a nice camera moving about and some simple cube objects, at the moment. Currently using vertex arrays, but I'm swapping to VBOs pretty quick here. I'm just trying to enable culling, however I'm not sure what order in which I ought to specify my vertices, right now this is what I'm doing:

```
void cube::update_verts(){
GLushort cur=0;

///back face
verts[cur++]=x; verts[cur++]=y; verts[cur++]=z;
verts[cur++]=x+sx; verts[cur++]=y; verts[cur++]=z;
verts[cur++]=x+sx; verts[cur++]=y+sy; verts[cur++]=z;
verts[cur++]=x; verts[cur++]=y+sy; verts[cur++]=z;

///right face
verts[cur++]=x+sx; verts[cur++]=y+sy; verts[cur++]=z;
verts[cur++]=x+sx; verts[cur++]=y; verts[cur++]=z;
verts[cur++]=x+sx; verts[cur++]=y; verts[cur++]=z+sz;
verts[cur++]=x+sx; verts[cur++]=y+sy; verts[cur++]=z+sz;

///top face
verts[cur++]=x+sx; verts[cur++]=y+sy; verts[cur++]=z;
verts[cur++]=x; verts[cur++]=y+sy; verts[cur++]=z;
verts[cur++]=x; verts[cur++]=y+sy; verts[cur++]=z+sz;
verts[cur++]=x+sx; verts[cur++]=y+sy; verts[cur++]=z+sz;

///front face
verts[cur++]=x; verts[cur++]=y; verts[cur++]=z+sz;
verts[cur++]=x+sx; verts[cur++]=y; verts[cur++]=z+sz;
verts[cur++]=x+sx; verts[cur++]=y+sy; verts[cur++]=z+sz;
verts[cur++]=x; verts[cur++]=y+sy; verts[cur++]=z+sz;

///bottom face
verts[cur++]=x+sx; verts[cur++]=y; verts[cur++]=z;
verts[cur++]=x; verts[cur++]=y; verts[cur++]=z;
verts[cur++]=x; verts[cur++]=y; verts[cur++]=z+sz;
verts[cur++]=x+sx; verts[cur++]=y; verts[cur++]=z+sz;

///left face
verts[cur++]=x; verts[cur++]=y+sy; verts[cur++]=z;
verts[cur++]=x; verts[cur++]=y; verts[cur++]=z;
verts[cur++]=x; verts[cur++]=y; verts[cur++]=z+sz;
verts[cur++]=x; verts[cur++]=y+sy; verts[cur++]=z+sz;


}

///Drawing Code:

glVertexPointer(3,GL_FLOAT,0,object.verts);
glColorPointer(3,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,0,object.colors);
glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS,0,6*4);
```

However it's definitely quite wrong, because when I `glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);` my cubes don't show the correct faces (as seen below).

**Normal**
[image: Regular View From Top]

**Problem Child**
[image: View From Side]

With both of these images culling is enabled.

In what order should I specify the vertices?

---

(EDIT) **Updated Working Function:**

```
void cube::update_verts(){
GLushort cur=0;

///top face
verts[cur++]=x; verts[cur++]=y+sy; verts[cur++]=z;
verts[cur++]=x; verts[cur++]=y+sy; verts[cur++]=z+sz;
verts[cur++]=x+sx; verts[cur++]=y+sy; verts[cur++]=z+sz;
verts[cur++]=x+sx; verts[cur++]=y+sy; verts[cur++]=z;


///bottom face
verts[cur++]=x; verts[cur++]=y; verts[cur++]=z;
verts[cur++]=x+sx; verts[cur++]=y; verts[cur++]=z;
verts[cur++]=x+sx; verts[cur++]=y; verts[cur++]=z+sz;
verts[cur++]=x; verts[cur++]=y; verts[cur++]=z+sz;

///left face
verts[cur++]=x; verts[cur++]=y; verts[cur++]=z;
verts[cur++]=x; verts[cur++]=y; verts[cur++]=z+sz;
verts[cur++]=x; verts[cur++]=y+sy; verts[cur++]=z+sz;
verts[cur++]=x; verts[cur++]=y+sy; verts[cur++]=z;

///right face
verts[cur++]=x+sx; verts[cur++]=y; verts[cur++]=z;
verts[cur++]=x+sx; verts[cur++]=y+sy; verts[cur++]=z;
verts[cur++]=x+sx; verts[cur++]=y+sy; verts[cur++]=z+sz;
verts[cur++]=x+sx; verts[cur++]=y; verts[cur++]=z+sz;

///front face
verts[cur++]=x; verts[cur++]=y; verts[cur++]=z+sz;
verts[cur++]=x+sx; verts[cur++]=y; verts[cur++]=z+sz;
verts[cur++]=x+sx; verts[cur++]=y+sy; verts[cur++]=z+sz;
verts[cur++]=x; verts[cur++]=y+sy; verts[cur++]=z+sz;


///back face
verts[cur++]=x; verts[cur++]=y; verts[cur++]=z;
verts[cur++]=x; verts[cur++]=y+sy; verts[cur++]=z;
verts[cur++]=x+sx; verts[cur++]=y+sy; verts[cur++]=z;
verts[cur++]=x+sx; verts[cur++]=y; verts[cur++]=z;

}
```

Answer (score 130, accepted):

By default?  In counter-clockwise order.

Consider a triangle facing the camera:

```
A
|\
| \
|  \
B---C
```

A->B->C would be front facing (counter-clockwise order), A->C->B would be rear-facing (clockwise order).

You can change which way OpenGL considers "front facing" via [`glFrontFace()`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glFrontFace.xhtml):

> The projection of a polygon to window coordinates is said to have
> clockwise winding if an imaginary object following the path from its
> first vertex, its second vertex, and so on, to its last vertex, and
> finally back to its first vertex, moves in a clockwise direction about
> the interior of the polygon.  The polygon's winding is said to be
> counterclockwise if the imaginary object following the same path moves
> in a counterclockwise direction about the interior of the polygon.
> `glFrontFace` specifies whether polygons with clockwise winding in
> window coordinates, or counterclockwise winding in window coordinates,
> are taken to be front-facing.  Passing `GL_CCW` to `mode` selects
> counterclockwise polygons as front-facing; `GL_CW` selects clockwise
> polygons as front-facing.
>
> **By default, counterclockwise polygons are taken to be front-facing.**

For ordering your vertices, consider an ideal cube:

```
  6---7
 /|  /|
2---3 |
| 4-|-5
|/  |/ 
0---1
```

For each face mentally rotate it to face the camera (your mind's eye):

```
Sides:
2---3  3---7  7---6  6---2
|   |  |   |  |   |  |   |
|   |  |   |  |   |  |   |
0---1  1---5  5---4  4---0

Bottom/Top:
0---1  6---7
|   |  |   |
|   |  |   |
4---5  2---3
```

Then you can just visually read off the quads or triangle pairs in the right counter-clockwise order:

```
2---3                3         2---3 
|   |  becomes      /|   and   |  / 
|   |             /  |         |/ 
0---1            0---1         0 

Triangles 0-1-3 and 0-3-2
Quad 0-1-3-2
```

It doesn't matter which vertex you start the triangle/quad with, for example with the first triangle `0-1-3`, `1-3-0`, and `3-0-1` are all equally valid, front-facing triangles.

Comment: Does it have to start with a particular vertex?

Comment: @Nikos: Nope, doesn't matter which vertex you start with.

Comment: @genpfault So as long as I'm sending vertices of triangles in counter-clockwise order (or in clockwise order in DirectX), one triangle at a time, it doesn't matter which vertex I start with. This triangle will be a front facing one and as such it will be rendered in the specific frame. Got it. Thank you. By the way, this is a great answer.

Comment: @genpfault I forgot to emphasize something else, something that some people may miss at first read. Not only which vertex you start with doesn't matter, but also which triangle you start with doesn't matter either! (I'm referring to the index buffer vertex indices.) No problem and thanks again!

Answer (score 8):

I learned another rule of thumb (literally) for determining the vertex order known as the "right hand rule".
Imagine your open hand (right) inside the cube with your thumb pointing towards the center of the cube.  If you then curl your hand into a fist, your fingers will pass the vertices in the correct order.  Since you are using your right hand for this it is called the "right hand rule".

Conversely, if you start with your left hand and point your thumb away from the center of the cube, your fingers will again sweep the vertices in the correct order.  This is known as the "left hand rule" (surprise).

Both methods work to give you counter-clockwise ordering.  For clockwise ordering, just use the opposite hand.

Comment: While you're right that counterclockwise is the default winding order (as it's called) for OpenGL, it might be useful to mention that the winding order is actually configurable using [glFrontFace](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glFrontFace.xml).

Comment: This is an old answer, but calling this the right hand rule is likely to cause a great deal of confusion.  When dealing with 3D euclidean geometry, the right hand rule almost always refers to the use of your right thumb, index, and middle finger to remember the configuration of the axes in a RH coordinate system, such as is typical in mathematics and OpenGL.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nested cube. Inner cube and outer cube using @genpfault's numbering of the cube faces. The data is in a *.ply (3D point cloud) format, with RGB color data as well.

If you copy and paste into a file, please be sure to check the newline termination for each line. I've added 2 spaces here as that is what's required (here on SO) to display a new line.

> ply
> format ascii 1.0
> element vertex 16
> property float32 x
> property float32 y
> property float32 z
> property uchar red
> property uchar green
> property uchar blue
> element face 24
> property list uint8 int32 vertex_indices
> end_header
> -4.00 -4.00 4.00 255 0 0
> 4.00 -4.00 4.00 255 0 0
> 4.00 4.00 4.00 255 0 0
> -4.00 4.00 4.00 255 0 0
> -4.00 -4.00 -4.00 255 0 0
> 4.00 -4.00 -4.00 255 0 0
> -4.00 4.00 -4.00 255 0 0
> 4.00 4.00 -4.00 255 0 0
> -6.00 -6.00 6.00 255 255 255
> 6.00 -6.00 6.00 255 255 255
> -6.00 6.00 6.00 255 255 255
> 6.00 6.00 6.00 255 255 255
> -6.00 -6.00 -6.00 255 255 255
> 6.00 -6.00 -6.00 255 255 255
> -6.00 6.00 -6.00 255 255 255
> 6.00 6.00 -6.00 255 255 255
> 3 0 1 2
> 3 1 3 2
> 3 1 5 3
> 3 5 7 3
> 3 5 4 7
> 3 4 6 7
> 3 4 0 6
> 3 0 2 6
> 3 4 5 0
> 3 5 1 0
> 3 2 3 6
> 3 3 7 6
> 3 8 9 10
> 3 9 11 10
> 3 9 13 11
> 3 13 15 11
> 3 13 12 15
> 3 12 14 15
> 3 12 8 14
> 3 8 10 14
> 3 12 13 8
> 3 13 9 8
> 3 10 11 14
> 3 11 15 14